# F#, R provider, R package tm and (almost) Ovid example

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

Mind that I am a beginner in F# and R (more so), so possibly point me to RTFM or otherwise ;-)

I have started looking into some text data mining with R, and the package tm.

I have the following script in R, which by the way are very much like the example for Ovid analysis (replace "lgtext" with "txt" for the real example and language="no" with language="lat" to run it with the Ovid example):

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)

txt <- system.file("texts", "lgtextfull", package = "tm")
(lgorg <- VCorpus(DirSource(txt, encoding = "UTF-8"), 
          readerControl = list(language = "no")))

lg <- tm_map(lgorg , stripWhitespace)
```

So as a starter I went for using F#, R, Deedle and RPRovider. Deedle I havent used yet so this may be disregarded...

I tried then to write the following F#:

```
#I "../packages/RProvider.1.0.17/"

#load "RProvider.fsx"

open RProvider
open RDotNet

open RProvider.``base``
open RProvider.tm
open RProvider.openNLP
open RProvider.SnowballC

let txt = R.system_file("texts", "lgtextfull", package = "tm", lib_loc = null, mustWork=true )
let lang =  dict [("language", "no":>obj)]
let readerControl = R.list(lang)
let dirsource = R.DirSource(txt, encoding = "UTF-8")

let lgorg = R.VCorpus(dirsource, readerControl)

let lg =  R.tm__map(lgorg, R.stripWhitespace)
```

The reason for "extending" the R script so much was for me to understand and make it work.

After some back and forth the above will run and apperently it works and reports in REPL same as in R, with exeption of the last line:

```
let lg =  R.tm__map(lgorg, R.stripWhitespace)
```

Which gives an error like:

```
System.Exception: No converter registered for type FSI_0006+lg@81 or any of its base types
   at RProvider.RInteropInternal.convertToR@164.Invoke(String message) in c:\Tomas\Public\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 164
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.go@523-3[b,c,d](String fmt, Int32 len, FSharpFunc`2 outputChar, FSharpFunc`2 outa, b os, FSharpFunc`2 finalize, FSharpList`1 args, Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.run@521[b,c,d](FSharpFunc`2 initialize, String fmt, Int32 len, FSharpList`1 args)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.capture@540[b,c,d](FSharpFunc`2 initialize, String fmt, Int32 len, FSharpList`1 args, Type ty, Int32 i)
   at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Reflect.Invoke@720-4.Invoke(T1 inp)
   at RProvider.RInteropInternal.REngine.SetValue(REngine this, Object value, FSharpOption`1 symbolName) in c:\Tomas\Public\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 274
   at RProvider.RInteropInternal.toR(Object value) in c:\Tomas\Public\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 287
   at RProvider.RInterop.passArg@431(List`1 tempSymbols, Object arg) in c:\Tomas\Public\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 445
   at RProvider.RInterop.argList@452-1.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in c:\Tomas\Public\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 453
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RProvider.RInterop.callFunc(String packageName, String funcName, IEnumerable`1 argsByName, Object[] varArgs) in c:\Tomas\Public\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 450
   at RProvider.RInterop.call(String packageName, String funcName, String serializedRVal, Object[] namedArgs, Object[] varArgs) in c:\Tomas\Public\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 494
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0006>.$FSI_0006.main@() in C:\Users\helgeu\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DisqusAnalyzer\DisqusAnalyzer.Lib\InteractiveSession.fsx:line 81
Stopped due to error
```

I must admit that I understand nothing of this and google.com doesnt help me either ;-)

Anyone? Any pointers? Should it work? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is that the second parameter to `tm__map` is an R function. When you write `R.stripWhitespace`, you get an F# closure, which we are not able  to convert back to an R function.

A workaround might be to evaluate an expression that returns the R function as `SymbolicExpression` and then pass it as the argument:

```
let stripWhite = R.eval(R.parse(text="stripWhitespace"))
let lg =  R.tm__map(lgorg, stripWhite)
```

Comment: Now I see it it explained it kind of makes sense to me. I have not looked at it very much yet, but I did try a quick one like you have described, and it did not work as expected that either. There was some success as described in stackoverflow.com/questions/28498549/…, so I will take a closer look and try out some more options and possibly post some follow up then. I have a strong suspicion that I try to write R in F# instead of using R in F#, in short. Anyway:Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by Tomas Petricek doesn't work, because *stripWhitespace* function comes from *tm* package. To make this work you should use fully qualified name of the function:

```
let stripWhitespace= R.eval(R.parse(text="tm::stripWhitespace"))
let lg = R.tm__map(lgorg, stripWhitespace)
```

This will do the trick.